# set height programmatically for mapfragment in xamarin android

Tags: xamarin.android

I am using xamarin android.

I want to set the height for the below fragment tag programmatically.

```
<fragment
                android:id="@+id/googlemap"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Could anyone please advice me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var mapFragment = (MapFragment)FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.googlemap);

mapFragment.View.LayoutParameters.Height = 500; //The size you decide
mapFragment.View.LayoutParameters.Width = 500; //The size you decide
```